# preventing easycsv::fread_zip from saving extracted files

Tags: r, unzip, fread

I want to load (many) .zip files, each containing (many) txt files. I understand that one simple way is to use easycsv::fread_zip (or easycsv::fread_folder for multiple zip files). This seems to work but has the undesirable property of automatically saving all the extracted files in my R project root directory, which seems to be an undocumented feature of those functions (unless I missed it!). Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there an alternative to easycsv::fread_zip? thanks

So for example

```
require(easycsv)
  filezip <- system.file("exampleZips", "example_tables.zip", package="easycsv")
  fread_zip(filezip)

  fread_zip(filezip, extension = "CSV")
```

creates these files in my R project root directory

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to a temporary directory, run fread_zip and change back.  The temporary directory will be removed when you exit R.

Note that `require` should only be used within an `if` to ensure that if there is a problem it is caught at that point. To load a package without `if` use `library`.

```
library(easycsv)

odir <- setwd(tempdir(check = TRUE))
fread_zip(filezip)
setwd(odir)
```

Alternately consider using your own function. This does not use easycsv except for the input test file.

```
library(data.table)

# fread those files from zip file at full path x whose names match pat
# returning list of data tables.
read_zip <- function(x, pat = "\\.csv$") {
  on.exit({ file.remove(Files); setwd(odir) })
  odir <- setwd(tempdir(check = TRUE))
  Files <- unzip(zipfile = x)
  Map(fread, grep(pat, Files, value = TRUE))
}

# test
filezip <- system.file("exampleZips", "example_tables.zip", package="easycsv")
L <- read_zip(filezip)
# list2env(L, .GlobalEnv) # optionally put data tables in global env
```

Comment: Both work, thanks! especially the suggested function read_zip works beautifully!